# Error 403 when trying to install the ingest-attachment plugin to elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I would like to install the ingest-attachement plugin to elasticsearch 6.8.23 on a debian 11:

When doing

```
user@server[elasticsearch]$ sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-attachment
```

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/ingest-attachment/ingest-attachment-6.8.23.zip
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1924)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.downloadZip(InstallPluginCommand.java:381)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.downloadAndValidate(InstallPluginCommand.java:455)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.download(InstallPluginCommand.java:257)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginCommand.java:230)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginCommand.java:217)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginCli.main(PluginCli.java:47)
```

However, when I browse to https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/ingest-attachment/ingest-attachment-6.8.23.zip there is no error 403 and the package gets downloaded.

Due to circumstances I have to use 6.8.23 so no need to commment on this. I know, I know ..

Any chance to install this on a Debian 11? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi kghbln, could you please try to download the package directly from the server with e.g., this command ( wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/ingest-attachment/ingest-attachment-6.8.23.zip) I suspect, the server is using an HTTP Proxy that don't allow the server to reach artifacts.elastic.co. 403 means permission error and it can come also from the proxy

Comment: `sudo wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/ingest-attachment/ingest-attachment-6.8.23.zip` works. How do I install the plugin after having fetched it via wget? `install ingest-attachement` does not work for this route.

Comment: Does this link help? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/8.4/plugin-authors.html#_testing_your_plugin you need to substitute the http url with a file-bases one file:///path-to-the-plugin

Comment: Affirmative. Doing `sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:///usr/share/elasticsearch/ingest-attachment-6.8.23.zip`after fetching the zip file with wget indeed allows to install the plugin. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
user@server[elasticsearch]$ sudo wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/ingest-attachment/ingest-attachment-6.8.23.zip`
```

followed by

```
user@server[elasticsearch]$ sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:///usr/share/elasticsearch/ingest-attachment-6.8.23.zip
```

does the trick!

Thanks a ton to @Briomkez for the solution!